# Why are there no file insertion syscalls

Tags: files, file-copy, system-calls

To my understanding, for manipulating files there is only the sys_write syscall in Linux, which overwrites the file content (or extends it, if at the end).

**Why are there no syscalls for inserting or deleting content in files in Linux?**

As all current file systems do not require the file to be stored in a continuous memory block, an efficient implementation should be possible.
(The files would get fragmented.)

With file system features as "copy on write" or "transparent file compression", the current way of inserting content seems to be very inefficient.

Comment: As with all fancy file operations, such an operation is much less useful in practice than it appears. The main use for such a thing are very specialized applications, like databases, emulators and such. The way you usually "edit" a file is by creating a newfile and and have a "save" operation by the user rename the new file to the old.

Comment: On a historical note, many years ago, systems might have provided "line-indexed" files, where you could insert a line between existing lines without moving any old data. One example from the 1970's is MIT's MTS [line files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MTS_system_architecture#Files) *line-oriented files which are indexed (and randomly accessible) by line number.*

Comment: @mosvy, but is the "create new file, then rename" concept used because it's good in itself, or exactly because the system doesn't provide any better way? Especially on text files operations like "modify this line (changing the length)" or "insert these lines here" are rather common, so one could assume that filesystem operations for those exact functions would be used if they were there. Of course, _not_ having them makes the fs implementation much simpler...

Comment: You can also manipulate file contents by `mmap(2)`ping them into the address space of your process. That way you can change data in the middle of the file, but you can only overwrite bytes that we already there. So inserting or deleting data in the middle of a file can not be done this way.

Comment: @meuh OpenVMS still does, via RMS (Record Management Services).

Comment: UNIX started a move *away* from providing record management systems inside the file system.

Comment: @ilkkachu it's good in itself, absolutely no doubt ;-) Even more, If inodes were immutable, that will make implementing block sharing, versioning, and almost *everything* much more efficient (and much more simple to reason about). Think by analogy how all script languages have switched to immutable strings -- but I'll cut it short here; it's hard to talk off the cuff about filesystems and not sound like a quack ;-)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

On recent Linux systems that is actually possible, but with *block* (4096 most of the time), not *byte* granularity, and only on some filesystems (ext4 and xfs).

Quoting from the [`fallocate(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fallocate.2.html) manpage:

> `int fallocate(int fd, int mode, off_t offset, off_t len);`
>
> [...]
>
> **Collapsing file space**
>
> Specifying the `FALLOC_FL_COLLAPSE_RANGE` flag  (available  since  Linux
>          3.15) in `mode` removes a byte range from a file, without leaving a hole.
>          The byte range to be collapsed starts at `offset` and continues  for  `len`
>          bytes.   At  the  completion of the operation, the contents of the file
>          starting at the location `offset+len` will be appended  at  the  location
>          `offset`, and the file will be `len` bytes smaller.
>
> [...]
>
> **Increasing file space**
>
> Specifying  the `FALLOC_FL_INSERT_RANGE` flag (available since Linux 4.1)
>          in `mode` increases the file space by inserting a hole  within  the  file
>          size  without  overwriting  any  existing data.  The hole will start at
>          `offset` and continue for `len` bytes.   When  inserting  the  hole  inside
>          file,  the  contents  of  the  file  starting at `offset` will be shifted
>          upward (i.e., to a higher file offset) by `len` bytes.  Inserting a  hole
>          inside a file increases the file size by `len` bytes.

Answer (score 9):

> As all current file systems do not require the file to be stored in a continuous memory block,

Filesystems might not require files to be stored in a continuous area (and that would be very inflexible indeed), but usually files are stored in fixed-size blocks (or sequences of contiguous blocks). Doing it that way simplifies the implementation, and the blocks are usually multiples of the block size of the underlying device.

So, implementing inserts of blocks with arbitrary length would make the file system format and implementation rather more complex or require moving potentially large amounts of data around. Neither of those is really good, and complex data structures can be built in userspace on top of the filesystem API.